# How do you translate "media file"

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

Wikipedia have an article for [Plurmedio](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plurmedio). But *medio* stands for *environment*.

You can find *aŭdvidaĵaj dosieroj* here and there as a translation, but a multimedia file can contain text, 3D assets, and so on, so the adjective is at best misguiding.

[Komputeko](http://komputeko.net/index_eo.php?vorto=media) also have

- *crossmedia* translated as   *plurkomunikila*. Leaving alone the "cross" lexem, *komunikil/a* seems less problematic than the two previous one, although to my mind not enough accurate, and the [PIV defintion](http://vortaro.net/#komunikilo) doesn't match perfectly.
- datumportilo, constructed as "semaphore" (the thing porting some meaning)
- *[registraĵo](http://vortaro.net/#registra%C4%B5o)* which is to my mind the best option I found so far.

Maybe one may build a better word, like "ajn-daten-tipo", do "ajntipa dosiero" or "ajnspeca dosiero".

Do you know any other, possibly better, option?

Answer (score 3):

I would just say *dosiero* since it already understood that files can be of different types.

If you have to be specific:

- filmeta dosiero
- sona dosiero
- teksta dosiero

Comment: Well, the thing is to specifically say the file have potentially several types. To give more context, I'm translating [documentation of Mediawiki](https://translatewiki.net/w/i.php?title=Special:Translate&group=mediawiki&language=eo&filter=&action=translate), and related projects.

Comment: Thus said, your answer seems relevant to my mind.